# MacBook Pro 2016 15 inch screen hinge feels loose

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I just purchased a 15 inch MBP, and the screen hinge feels a little loose, at least compared to my 2011 15 inch MBP.

Is this normal?

Comment: Whether this is normal is going to be subjective, so you may get different opinions. If you're worried why not visit the store you bought it from to check? Or if you bought it online, go to any retailer who sells Apple products and see what their display models feel like?